# Build fails only in docker while using Vite for Fullcalendar package

Tags: reactjs, docker, fullcalendar, vite

I'm currently building a calendar based app and it was working and building fine. Recently I used a package called FullCalendar for react, ever since, I'm getting the following error.

Here is the error log:

```
#11 5.591 vite v4.3.1 building for production...
#11 5.682 2023-04-26T14:27:15.055Z vite:esbuild 156.99ms tsconfck init /home/scd
#11 5.855 transforming...
#11 10.29 ✓ 26 modules transformed.
#11 10.30 ✓ built in 4.69s
#11 10.30 [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@fullcalendar/react" from "/home/scd/src/pages/schedule/index.jsx".
#11 10.30 This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
#11 10.30 If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
#11 10.30 `build.rollupOptions.external`
#11 10.31 error during build:
#11 10.31 Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@fullcalendar/react" from "/home/scd/src/pages/schedule/index.jsx".
#11 10.31 This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
#11 10.31 If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
#11 10.31 `build.rollupOptions.external`
#11 10.31     at viteWarn (file:///home/scd/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-24daf00c.js:46525:23)
#11 10.31     at onwarn (/home/scd/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react/dist/index.cjs:257:9)
#11 10.31     at onRollupWarning (file:///home/scd/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-24daf00c.js:46546:9)
#11 10.31     at onwarn (file:///home/scd/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-24daf00c.js:46296:13)
#11 10.31     at Object.onwarn (file:///home/scd/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25280:13)
#11 10.31     at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///home/scd/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23915:26)
#11 10.31     at file:///home/scd/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23875:26
#11 10.31     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Note: This only happens in the docker, it is building fine in my local machine.

For docker, I'm using node:latest or node:16-slim image.
For Mac, I'm on node version 16.x.x

I tried the suggestion rollOutOptions, but app is not working after the build.

When I build it using rolloutoptions, then in the console I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@fullcalendar/react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Please let me know what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance

Trying to build the vite app in Docker and running into above errors

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-buster-slim AS build

RUN mkdir -p /home/scd/ && chown -R node: /home/scd

WORKDIR /home/scd

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN node node_modules/esbuild/install.js

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "specialui",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build --debug",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.12.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.2.1",
    "@nivo/bar": "^0.80.0",
    "@nivo/core": "^0.80.0",
    "@nivo/geo": "^0.80.0",
    "@nivo/line": "^0.80.0",
    "@nivo/pie": "^0.80.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^1.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.15.0",
    "yup": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```